# how to get video's real size in html5

Tags: html, video

to play video in html5 correctly,i save the videoWidth and videoHeight values of video when capturing loadedmetadata event.what surprised me is that both the values are 100 on my android browse while 480*640 on my iphone safari which is the real size. to find the reason, i've tried other browsers such as chrome,uc.i am surprised to find that the values of videoWidth and videoHeight are wrong under various android browses.why?can anybody help!

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have too 100 with and height dimensions

Answer (score 1):

it appears the issue is with metadata loading and when you query the size too early you get the default 100x100.
if you do a specific check after the durationchange event shows a duration greater than 1s then you will see correct values for the videoWidth and videoHeight
(I've found with HTML5 video in Android that relying on anything before the duration shows greater than the initial default of 1s is problematic)

Comment: __durationchange__ - that's what I was looking for, since __loadedmetadata__ doesn't work in Android! Thanks!